# Copy tunes to 2nd PC without syncing

Tags: itunes, drm

I just purchased an album on iTunes on work PC but can't sync because it will delete all my existing tunes from the iPad (I only sync with my music at home).

Can I copy the files to my home PC manually and sync there, or will that not work because of DRM issues ?

Comment: You want to add a DRM protected music file from one iTunes to another iTunes in another PC?

Comment: Yes (I am assume all tunes bought on the iStore are DRM protected).

Comment: Everything except iTunes Plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same iTunes account you bought the music from on the other machine, you'll be OK. Just go to that machine and choose `Store -> Authorize this computer...`. You can have up to 5 computers authorized to play your DRM'd music. Also, if you want to transfer music off an iPod, there are ways to do that without erasing it. [Here's a link](http://www.macworld.com/article/145725/2010/01/ipodextraction_roundup.html) with info on apps for that.

Comment: My home computer is already authorised. The music was downloaded at work. I can't sync to my iPhone at work cos it will erase all the music on the phone, and I can't re-download it from iStore onto my home PC. How the heck do I do this?

Comment: So I solved this by syncing at work which did erase all tunes from my iPhone and added only the album I had purchased. Then at home clicked the "Transfer purchases" option to copy the album to iTunes, the re-synced to get everything back. They don't make it easy do they?